# is int32_t considered one of the extended signed integer types under section 6.2.5/4?

Tags: c, types, integer, standards

Is this understanding correct: any integer that is not `signed char, short, int, long, long long` is an extended signed integer type under section 6.2.5/4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily. `int32_t` and Co are usually just `typedef`s to standard integer types.

I don't know of any platform that implements extended integer types in the sense of the standard. On 64 bit platforms gcc e.g has `__int128_t` (or so), but it doesn't fulfill the requirements of an extended integer type as required by the standard.